# How to use grammar book examples in real life

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

English grammar books often use these kind of examples to explain the difference between the use of the present perfect simple and progressive:

"I can see you have painted your room, it looks great!" the focus is on the result = the painted room, which is finished and looks great.

"You have got paint in your hair and on your clothes, have you been painting?" the focus is on the process of painting, which results in the unintended side-effect of getting paint all over you. It doesn't matter whether the painting is finished or not.

These examples I understand.

My question is: Can I say: "Your room looks great, have you been painting?" meaning the painting is finished and has a desired result, it looks great.

This example is not used in grammar books, but I think it is idiomatic. Am I right?

Comment: I think most people would say "...have you just painted it?" or words to that effect, but not " have you been painting?"

Comment: @Kate Bunting: could you explain why? What is wrong with "have you been painting?"

Comment: For the very reason that you give; that that question is more likely to refer to the activity than the finished result.